# What command to change color when user click the text and icon

Tags: android, xml

I tried to find the green color where they code when user click. I know how to change color but i don't know how to command for a user click the text and icon will change into another color. Tired to find that

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a default template project with Navigation Drawer in Android Studio, it depends on the color listed as the `colorPrimary` in `colors.xml` under `res`. Change the default color `#008577` to red like this and run the project to see the change:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#ff0000</color>
```